# Three.js - Loading VRML file with indexedfaceset and color

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d

I have a simple VRML file that I can load in existing VRML viewer:

[VRML working example in existing viewer](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FDI7q.jpg)

I have tried to load it with Three.js, but I cannot manage to obtain the color on each face:

[VRML loaded in three.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/r1KH4.jpg)

Please find below the VRML file:

```
#VRML V2.0 utf8
#Color example: a pyramid
Shape {
appearance Appearance{
    material Material { }
    }
geometry IndexedFaceSet {
    coord Coordinate {
                point [
            # bottom 
            -1.0 -1.0 1.0,  #vertex 0
            1.0 -1.0 1.0,   #vertex 1
            1.0 -1.0 -1.0,  #vertex 2
            -1.0 -1.0 -1.0, #vertex 3
            # top
            0.0 1.0 0.0     #vertex 4
                ]
            }
colorPerVertex FALSE #so each face will have one of the colors
color Color {
                color [
                    1.0 0.0 0.0,#color 0
                    0.0 1.0 0.0,#color 1
                    0.0 0.0 1.0,#color 2
                    1.0 1.0 0.0,#color 3
                    0.0 1.0 1.0,#color 4
                ]
            }
colorIndex [ 2 3 4 0 0 ] #the first face will have color 2, the 2nd color3...
    coordIndex [
        #bottom square
         0, 3, 2, 1, 0, -1,
        #side1
         0, 1, 4, -1,
        #side2
         1, 2, 4, -1,
        #side3
         2, 3, 4, -1,
        #side1
         3, 0, 4, -1,
        ]

}
}
```

=> Is it the VRML loader that does not support indxedfaceset and color associated ?